# On reasoning for checking zeros for MIMO transfer function matrix

Tags: matrices, control-theory

For a nonsquare transfer function matrix of a MIMO system, how to find out if the system has no zeros in an analytical (rather computational) way.

> **Note:** It is easy to use computational methods such as Smith-Mcmillan to obtain zeros and poles.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand the question. So, you are given a matrix $G(s)$ and you want to check if all its elements have on zeros? Or what? What is your available information?

Comment: I guess with M<>N you mean non-square transfer function matrices?

Comment: @SampleTime,Yes, it's true.

Comment: @Arastas, It seems that the OP is misleading for you. I mean https://ece.gmu.edu/~gbeale/ece_720/smith-mcmillan.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When representing the system as a state space model

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A\,x + B\,u, \\
y &= C\,x + D\,u,
\end{align}

such that the transfer function matrix is equal to $G(s) = C(s\,I-A)^{-1}B+D$, then the (transmission) zeros can be calculated by solving the generalized eigenvalue problem

$$
\det\!\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{bmatrix} - \lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\right) = 0.
$$

So essentially you need to calculate the roots of some resulting polynomial. In general closed-form solutions for the roots of polynomials can only be calculated for polynomials up to an order of four. Higher order polynomials can not be solved analytically in general.